# Flutter: Sideways scrollable list view transition from grid view

Tags: listview, flutter, gridview

I have a flutter app whereby I have a grid view containing images and when a user clicks on a certain image on that grid view it navigates him to the detail page of that image. I would like to however have it such that when the user clicks on the grid view image, the page he is taken to is a horizontal scroll list view with the selected image as the current list item and the items to the left and right would be the items to the left and right of the current item in the grid view.
Any ideas on how I can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I have found this package https://pub.dev/packages/indexed_list_view  it seems to achieve what I want, might help someone in future